Nextjs api is not updated
I have uploaded my Nextjs project to Vercel, but I have the following problem, my api route is not updating automatically. When new entries are added to the database, they are not fetched by the api.
Here is the api:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

export async function GET() {


    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'placeholder',
        user: 'placeholder',
        password: 'placeholder',
        database: 'placeholder',
    });
    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM orders';
        const [data] = await connection.execute(query);
       
        return NextResponse.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Fehler', error);
        return NextResponse.json({
            error: 'Datenbankabfrage fehlgeschlagen'
        }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

I have already tried it with useRouter(), but it could also be that I have used it incorrectly, otherwise I have not found anything about it so far

This reason might be next.js caching, nextjs caches reoccurent requests for the same endpoint, can you provide the code where you are calling this API endpoint ?, you can add next: { revalidate: 0 } in your fetch config to check if it is what's causing this behaviour.
